# Apple Game Center - Unlinking games

Tags: iphone, games

I have games challenging me that I have not had on my phone for years...Please help me remove them as it drives me crazy!

Comment: Can you provide more information like the name of the games, if they are fully deleted, etc.?  This will help in generating useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Simply open Game Center on your iPhone, switch to the games tab and swipe left on the games you want to remove. This will present you with a delete button.